# Loop para repetir as chaves anteriores (3, 32, 321, ...)

Tags: php, loop, recursão

Estou tentando fazer um *breadcrumb* dinâmico e preciso fazer um loop para montar o link. A cada loop, ele precisa repetir os itens anteriores, como no exemplo abaixo o array e o output.

```
array( array( 'Bairro' , 'bairro' ) , array( 'Rua' , 'rua' ) )

<a href="bairro">Bairro</a>
<a href="bairro/rua">Rua</a>
```

O pouco que consegui foi usando unset para gerar um novo array. Após esse *for* para montar a *repetição*, eu ainda preciso de mais 2 loops e reverter a ordem. Uma baita gambiarra.

```
foreach( $list as $i => $item ){
    $newlist[] = $list;
    unset( $list[$i] );
}
```

Comment: Só uma pergunta: o label do breadcrumb precisa mesmo ocupar outra posição na tua array? Não seria melhor ser um array associativo? Ex.: `array('item' => 'Label', 'bairro' => 'Bairro', 'rua' => 'Rua')`

Comment: @Thomas, Seria melhor sim, mas como disse, é dinâmico e com vários sub itens. Se pudesse refazer o array não teria problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que acumulando o link em uma variável você consiga o resultado que espera, por exemplo:

```
$breadcrumbs = array( array( 'Bairro' , 'bairro' ) , array( 'Rua' , 'rua' ) );

foreach ( $breadcrumbs as $item ) {
    $link_acumulado .= $item[1] . '/';

    echo '<a href="' . trim( $link_acumulado, '/' ) . '">' . $item[0] . '</a>';
}
```

**Saída:**

```
<a href="bairro">Bairro</a>
<a href="bairro/rua">Rua</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vou deixar outra possibilidade, mais complexa e menos performática que a do Márcio, mas ainda assim válida.

Se você [transpor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3423692/753531) a matriz original vai ter sempre um array de dois índices, um com os *labels* e outro com os *breadcrumbs*.

Combine os índices numa nova matriz (aqui descrita como **$breadcrumbs**) e itere:

```
$previous = NULL;

$last = key( array_slice( $breadcrumbs, -1, 1, TRUE ) );
$separator = ' &raquo; ';

foreach( $breadcrumbs as $label => $breadcrumb ) {

    $previous .= sprintf( '/%s', $breadcrumb );

    if( $label == $last ) $separator = NULL;

    printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>%s', $previous, $label, $separator );
}
```

Comment: Valeu Bruno, o problema é a ordem do array. Achei mais prático trabalhar em pares..